# Qt for Python: create encapsulated qml modules with python

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I wish to create a project structure like this:

```
parent.qml
parent.py
./child
    |---child.qml
    |---child.py
```

From within `parent` module, I hope to import `child` module.

Essentially, there is a `child` module with encapsulated ui (`child.qml`) and business logic (`child.py`). I want the `child`'s business logic to be encapsulated within `child/child.py`. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: is there error, or failed import with the current structure you provided?

Comment: @eyllanesc my question is more general. I don't know how to achieve this. I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: @KevenWang There are many forms of interaction between QML and the backend (C++, python, etc.), which is why I am asking you for a real code: an MRE. Otherwise it would be too broad and confusing.

Comment: @eyllanesc let me rephrase: I'm asking what's the best practices / recommended method of accomplishing this? I'm using python with QML. "There are many forms of interaction between QML and the backend" the "form" is precisely what I'm asking about here. If I had a MRE, then I would not be asking this question.